# OutputPath when using multiple TargetFrameworks

Tags: visual-studio-2019, csproj

How to specify output path only for single target framework in new SDK csproj project style.

My project file has this PropertyGroup:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I tried to add something like this above this group but didn't worked:

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition=" '$(MyMsbuildParam)' == 'False' ">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <TargetFrameworks>net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0;net472</TargetFrameworks>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <When Condition=" '$(MyMsbuildParam)' == 'True' ">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <TargetFrameworks>net472</TargetFrameworks>
            <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
            <OutputPath >..\bin64\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
</Choose>
```

This is the error I'm getting:
Error   MSB4044 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task was not given a value for the required parameter "TargetFramework".
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    241

Comment: Looks like some evaluation step was performed without setting the `MyMsbuildParam` - e.g. an implicit restore or loading from an IDE. However - what is your goal here? Use the same csproj file in different situations or keep the multi-targeting and set different specific output paths for both target frameworks?

Comment: The idea was to keep multi-targeting of the project for development purposes and to specify output path  for production build as msbuild parameter used by build server. I ended up adding postbuild event which is coping resulting assemblies after build is complete.